# Alternatives to ItemGroup/Compile and App_Code for running/debugging C# in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, orchardcms, app-code

In Web Applications, we add .cs files to the .csproj's `Project/ItemGroup/Compile.Include` attribute. This inputs the file into the build, which compiles it into a bin folder assembly.

In Websites, we add .cs files to the App_Code folder. The files compiles at run time.

Not to add a .cs file to either `ItemGroup/Compile.Include` or App_Code means that the compiler will not run the code.

Are there any other ways to make a .cs file run?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? And, BTW, I recommend you avoid web sites at all costs.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I am trying to add a C# file to an Orchard CMS theme. I have done it via a csproj file, and I am wondering if there is another way.

Comment: A csproj in the theme is how it's done. Having code in a theme is kind of a smell however. What do you need it for?